# Is there a hidden '\n' be added when create a file by vim?

Tags: vim, base64

when I create a file by vim with content `12`, it show size is **3** Bytes not **2** Bytes

[image: img1]

so is a hidden char here I guess?
then I base64 it, result is `MTIK` that base64 of `12\n`
not `MTI=` that correct base64 of `12`

[image: img2]

Where is the `\n` from?

Comment: The newline isn't _hidden_ at all. it is clearly visible that the prompt after the `cat` output is on a new line.

Comment: If you *really* want to create a file without that final newline character on the last line, you can `:set noeol`, then `:set binary` and write the file. But I agree with Armali, it's not hidden, it's just part of the format for text files, that the last line is finished by a newline character (unless you're working on a Mac).

Comment: @Armali.  I said it is hidden because when `wc -l a.txt`,  result is 1 not 2.
I didn't know the `end of line` ago

Comment: @joanis. yes, now I finally know.

Answer (score 2):

It is customary among Unix tools to end the last line with an "end of line" character, generally `LF` (`0x0A`), and to expect that character to be here. `nano` does that by default, `echo` does that by default, etc.

When in Vim, you can do `:set binary noendofline` (or the short version `:set bin noeol`) to tell Vim to skip the trailing `LF` when writing the file.

See `:help 'binary'` and `:help 'endofline'` for the many caveats of those options.